# Solder bend radius or tension radius or wetting distance

Tags: soldering

If I had a solder (like lead free SAC305) and I wanted to calculate what the radius would be on a given amount of solder, how would I do that?

[image]

Comment: Isn't that playing with the solder during its "plastic" temperature range?

Comment: run tests .....

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to just nail it instead of do two revs, I'm trying to figure out some pad size things, but it's between two different pads, I'm hoping that there is some way to figure out what the curve is on the soldler so I can design a good pad to pad configuration

Comment: you could ask a PCB manufacturer that does wave soldering ... they might talk to you

Comment: That's an idea...

Comment: This is related to the wetting physics, particularly the [contact angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_angle?useskin=vector). It'll depend on both materials in question, both the solder and the PCB finish.

Comment: Or are you talking about a pad of finite dimensions? In that case, it would depend more on the pad geometry than any solder properties, I think.

Comment: Just a rectangular pad, but the amount of silver also makes a difference because the more solder, the higher 'hill' it would make